# Calling web services from powershell: "Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction"

Tags: powershell, wsdl

I am attempting to call a web service from a powershell script.

I am not the author of the web service, nor do I know much about web services. (I'm only ramping up in PowerShell, as well.)

The vendor of the web software has provided me with a .wsdl file. I ran wsdl.exe against it, then csc.exe against the .cs file that was generated, in order to produce proxy .dll files.

In my powershell script, I am instantiating an object, setting its url property and attempting to call one of the methods:

```
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$ProxyDllPath\VendorProxy.dll")
    $myVar = new-object VendorObject
    $myVar.url = "http://servername/serverdirectory/serverfile.asmx"
    $myStuff = $myVar.GetStuff()
```

When I execute this, I get the exception:

```
Exception calling "GetStuff" with "0" argument(s): "Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: ."
At C:\users\xxx\desktop\xxx.ps1:56 char:55
+     $myStuff = $myVar.GetStuff<<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I have taken a network capture of my call and see:

```
POST /serverdirectory/serverfile.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.4927)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAt4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbAdAAAADw==
Host: servername
Content-Length: 0
```

The WSDL description for this webservice is:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetStuff">
  <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I'm afraid that I don't really understand the exception; as I said, web services is not an area where I claim competence.

How can I determine the soap action the server requires, and how do I configure my $myVar to use that soap action?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the "soapAction" will have the method name qualified with the namespace (like "http://tempuri.org/GetStuff" ).  You might need to check your asmx service.

If you are running PowerShell V2 (which you should be if you are able to) you could try building your proxy with [New-WebServiceProxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315258.aspx).

```
$MyProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri 'http://servername/serverdirectory/serverfile.asmx' -Namespace 'MyService'
```